# Чи я можу бути менш старим чоловіком?

Tags: прикметники, non-native-speaker

Can I be a less old man?

I’ve learned that a simple way to form comparative adjectives is to put *більш* or *менш*  before the adjective to mean *more* or *less*.

When translated literally, *менш цікавий* (less interesting) or *менш ввічливий* (less polite) sounds natural in English, however 
*менш довгий* (less long) or *менш великий* (less big) sound not quite right.

Is the same true in Ukrainian, or can *менш* and *більш* be used pretty much universally and sound correct?

Answer (score 2):

You are absolutely right.

> Ukrainian adjectives have two degrees of comparison: comparative and superlative. Every degree has as well two forms: simple and hard.
>
> First of all I would like to note that for beginners or even more
>   advanced Ukrainian speakers the "simple" form is actually more
>   difficult to understand and learn than the "hard" form. So feel free
>   to use the easiest form because they both are interchangeable, though
>   we prefer to use "hard" form with more abstract or relative
>   adjectives. Hard form is created by adding words більш (more), менш
>   (less) to the adjectives:
>
> цікавий (interesting) — більш цікавий (more interesting), менш цікавий
>   (less interesting)
>
> розвинений (advanced) — більш розвинений (more advanced), менш
>   розвинений (less advanced)
>
> The adjective does not change at all, all you need is to add a
>   specific word to it.
>
> Pay attention that unlike English where words "more" or "less" are
>   used with adjectives with more than three syllables, Ukrainian
>   "більш", "менш" are used with any adjectives no matter how many
>   syllables they have.
>
> As you can see this form of making comparative adjective is much
>   simplier than the previous one.

[ukrainiangrammar.com](http://ukrainiangrammar.com/article/2011-01-31/the-adjective-degrees-of-comparison.html)